# meet a/the target of . . .?

Tags: definite-article, indefinite-article

Should the definite or indefinite article be used in the following? The target in question is mentioned for the first time in the passage, yet it seems to be quite specific.

> Currently, the Ministry of Economic Affairs’ Bureau of Energy (BOE) has come up with a new two-year plan to promote the installation of solar PV facilities such as rooftop solar panels and ground-mounted solar panels. It aims to meet **a**/**the** target of 3.7 GW by the end of 2019, and 6.5 GW by the end of 2020.

I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: *Specific* – because the value is given? Are you saying it should always be ***the** <quantity> of <magnitude> <unit>*?

Comment: From the context, I'd ask if the target is negotiable. If the target is set by passing a law, for example, we are aiming to meet "the" target. If the BOE is merely naming a milestone they hope to reach, "meet a target of..." is the correct way to introduce that milestone.